# how to dynamically click the week header button on load of the calendar?

Tags: fullcalendar

When creating the calendar :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

     $('#list_reserv_salle').fullCalendar({
            lang: '<?php echo getLocale(); ?>',
            header: {
                        left: 'prev,next today',
                        center: 'title',
                        right: 'agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                    },
            defaultDate: '<?php echo GetTodayPgSQL(); ?>',
            editable: true,
            eventLimit: true
    });

});
```

then at runtime on first load the month view is shown :

[image]

I do not want to display this view , I want the agendaWeek view to be displayed. How to achieve that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the below option to get agendaWeek as default view

defaultView: 'agendaWeek'

Answer (score 0):

You can change the current view by calling the 'changeView' method:

```
//Change the current view to Week:
$('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'changeView', 'basicWeek ' );
```

Source: http://fullcalendar.io/docs/views/changeView/

You can also call the 'Today' method:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('today');
```